# nested conditionals assignment in #python3

Tags: python-3.x

I've been struggling with this code for almost a week now, and I've written it in so many different ways but I haven't found a single way that works 100 %.
Anyway, I'll post the task and my latest attempt, can you tell me what i'm doing wrong ?:

task:

Program: shirt order
First get input for color and size 
White has sizes L, M 
Blue has sizes M, S 
print available or unavailable, then
print the order confirmation of color and size 
hint: set a variable "available = False" before nested if statements and

### change to True if color and size are available

my code:

```
print ("welcome to our store, we have some great shirts on sale")

shirt_color = ("w" + "b")

shirt_size =("s" + "m" + "l")


available = False


first_color = input("please select a color: ")

choosen_color = first_color



if choosen_color.lower() in shirt_color.lower() == "w":

    second_size = input("please choose a size")


    choosen_size = second_size


    if choosen_size.lower() in shirt_size.lower() == "l":


        available = True


        print ("order confirmed")


        print (available)


    elif choosen_size.lower() in shirt_size.lower() == "m":

            available = True

    print ("order confirmed")

    print (available)

    if choosen_color.lower() in shirt_color.lower() == "b":

        second_size = input("please choose a size")

    choosen_size = second_size

    if choosen_size.lower() in shirt_size.lower() == "m":

        available = True

        print ("order confirmed")

        print (available)

    elif choosen_size.lower() in shirt_size.lower() == "s":

            available = True

    print ("order confirmed")

    print (available)

else:

    print ("not confirmed")

    print (available)
```

Comment: What is that you get, what is it that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The problematic parts are the conditional statements coded in the following way:
`choosen_color.lower() in shirt_color.lower() == "w"`

it is enough to check first if the `chosen_color` is valid (among the allowed colors):

```
choosen_color.lower() in shirt_color.lower()
```

and separately if it actually is one of the colors you want to check for:

```
choosen_color.lower() in shirt_color.lower() and choosen_color.lower() == "w"
```

Changing the code in a similar manner for the sizes should help you out to make the code work as you would want.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful I would be grateful for an upvote and / or accepting the answer as correct.